# VBA EXCEL filtering with Or criteria with 2 different rows

Tags: vba, filtering

I want to filter with 2 criteria with "Or" relationship between the two criteria. However, the 2 criteria are on 2 different rows. I want to filter the first row for number for 6 to 7 or the second row for the date of 2010/6/16 and 2010/7/1. How could I code for the filtering?

[My 2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z594.png)

Comment: By "row", do you mean "column"?  (And, whether you mean "row" or "column", it probably doesn't matter. You can't filter two columns with an "or" condition between the two filters. And you can't filter different rows using different conditions, irrespective of whether you use "and" or "or" or anything else.)

Comment: If you mean "column" though, the usual work-around is to add an extra column that has a formula such as `=OR(AND(A2>=6,A2<=7),B2=DATE(2010,6,17),B2=DATE(2010,7,1))` and then filter on that column being either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: I mean column, sorry for the confusion. That's a good solution. thanks